# Dual boot system failed, ubuntu file system missing during hard disk data recovery

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, data-recovery, system-recovery

I had a dual boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 18. Recently the system failed, the motherboard
probably got fried by lightning during a thunder storm and its not booting anymore, no fan, no lights, totally dead.

So I salvaged the hard disk to recover the data from it. I plugged in the hard disk to a windows machine using a SATA to USB adapter, but I can only see the windows file system in it, neither the linux partition is showing nor the files are showing anywhere else.

How can I recover the files I had in ubuntu, is there any other way to see hidden partitions?
Should I try plugging it directly into the SATA port instead of using a SATA to USB adapter? I have to invest in a new machine to do this and if it still cant access that data that investment will not be very fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu partitions will be ext4, so you won't be able to see them on Windows. There is some software you can use to read ext4, but I have never found anything that worked satisfactorily. Your best chance is probably using a Linux live USB drive. Instructions for creating one with Ubuntu can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Boot using the USB stick, and select the option to try Ubuntu without installing. Then you should be able to use Ubuntu's file manager/terminal to copy files from your old disk.